# SQL errors in insert statement VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into a specific column in my ORDERS table, using a text box input and finding the specific column by using another text box input.

```
Private Sub addCardBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addCardBtn.Click
        custConn.Open()

        'New sql Insert statement'
        Dim sqlStatement As String = "insert into ORDERS (CARD_NUMBER) ('" + cardNoTxt.Text + "') WHERE ORDER_ID" & orderIDTxt.Text
        commd = New OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, custConn)

        commd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'If record is added successfully show message box'
        MessageBox.Show("Card Number Saved", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        custConn.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: use SQL parameters and this type of error will become rare (in addition to avoiding SQL injection attacks).  Look at `sqlStatement` after you create it to see what you missed

Comment: please add `'` at the end of the comment lines so that the code highlighting on this website understands them.

Comment: The first this to do is get your sql statement working in management studio, then transfer it to code.

Comment: Thanks @jasen didn't know I had to

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, You want an `UPDATE` query?

```
Dim sqlStatement As String = "UPDATE ORDERS SET CARD_NUMBER = :CARDNO
                                   WHERE ORDER_ID = :ORDERID";
```

And always use bind variables. to avoid SQL*iInjection.

To explain in short what is `SQL*Injection`,

Adding `OR 1=1` to any logical expression will give a TRUE result always(`WHERE name = 'Mahesh' or 1=1` will fetch all the rows in my table..). So, When you construct SQL statements, like this, you are exposing a vulnerability of your query being tampered to have such things.

```
commd = New OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, custConn)
commd.Parameters.Add("CARDNO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = cardNoTxt.Text
commd.Parameters.Add("ORDERID", OracleType.VarChar).Value = orderIDTxt.Text

commd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

By binding the vales this way, you query is safe and not modifiable in runtime. Just the values of the binded variable changes. It also improves the query caching in the DBMS. And improves performance as well.